# 18.04 dual monitor issues

Tags: multiple-monitors

I recently upgraded from 16.04 lts to 18.04 lts.  In 16.04 I could use the two monitors as if it were one display, I could move windows right or left, from one screen to the other and the mouse cursor would move from one screen to the other, also right or left.  In 18.04 I can only move the window or the mouse cursor in one direction.  What am I doing wrong in 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Settings > Devices > Screen Display you can modify the way your monitors are setup.
It sounds like you want to have them set to 'Join Displays' you can then re-arrange them so you can drag windows in the correct direction.
[image]

Comment: I dont get the join - mirror - single display options on Screen Display and i see the screens mirrored at the moment. Any idea what i can do? running a Radeon 5770 and trying to install its drivers fails

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same situation. I tried and succeeded. You can try

1. I try to install another type of desktop interface, it can show two screens of me.

   ```
   $ sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop
   ```

   Make sure you use gdm3 to switch the desktop appearance. Then reboot with the new appearance
2. You login with the new desktop appearance, if it's two screens right now. Then you logout and login again with ubuntu appearance or ubunu wayland appearance. If you see two screens ... oh well
3. You must then remove the ubuntu-mate-desktop package, which will keep all configurations of your appearance.

   ```
   $ apt purge ubuntu-mate-desktop
   ```
4. Wish you good luck, before Ubuntu update